# How to keep Text as leading alignment after set Text().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

Tags: ios, layout, swiftui, geometryreader

It could be a simple case, but I couldn't find a solution.

**Here is my code**, using the GeometryReader to set the relative layout of SwiftUI view size like Image. The issue in on the last VStack, I want to background of Text to go to the right end of VStack. Thus, I set it as `Text("Haibo: asdasd").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` but after that I found the text became to horizontal centered and not followed the VStack alignment: .leading.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 12) {
                Image("Alan shore").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 6, height: geo.size.width / 6).cornerRadius(4)

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {

                   // name
                   Text("Haibo")
                   // content
                   Text("Think ThinkThink ThinkThink ThinkThink ThinkThink ThinkThink ThinkThink ThinkThink Think")
                   // 九宫格
                   VStack(spacing: 6) {

                       HStack(spacing: 6) {
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                       }
                       HStack(spacing: 6) {
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                       }
                       HStack(spacing: 6) {
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                           Image("Little girl").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width / 4.7, height: geo.size.width / 4.7)
                       }
                   }

                   // Time, Action
                   HStack {
                       Text("5 hour ago")
                       Spacer()
                       Image("moment-action")
                   }

                   // Comment
                   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                       Text("Haibo: asdasd").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                       Text("Jobs: WDC WDC WDC WDCWWWWW")
                   } //.padding(.init(top: 6, leading: 6, bottom: 6, trailing: 12))
                       .background(Color.yellow)
                   .cornerRadius(3)
                }
            } .padding(.init(top: 12, leading: 12, bottom: 12, trailing: 30))
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Well, please see the screenshot for better understanding, the `Text("Haibo: asdasd")` is centered in the yellow area. How could let it to be keep leading alignment?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a fairly confusing aspect of SwiftUI. The VStack alignment specifies how its elements align within the VStack frame, while the Text.frame alignment specifies how the text will align within the Text.frame.

I've found it helpful to add some borders as I'm debugging:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Haibo: asdasd")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .border(Color.red , width: 2.0)
    Text("Jobs: WDC WDC WDC WDCWWWWW")
        .border(Color.green , width: 2.0)
}
```

[image: original way with borders]

Now you can see that the Text with maxWidth: .infinity has a frame that spans the entire width of the VStack frame. The text frame *is* aligned leading, but the text within defaults to a center alignment.

It's worth mentioning here that the "jobs..." text is also center aligned to its text frame, but it's not obvious because the frame is sized to the text only, then the text frame itself is leading aligned within the VStack frame.

Now try this:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Haibo: asdasd")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .border(Color.red , width: 2.0)
    Text("Jobs: WDC WDC WDC WDCWWWWW")
        .border(Color.green , width: 2.0)
}
```

[image: new way with borders]

The text frame is still the full-width of the VStack frame, but the text is now aligned leading within the text frame.

Here's the snippet without the borders:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Haibo: asdasd")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    Text("Jobs: WDC WDC WDC WDCWWWWW")
}
```

[image: new way without borders]

Here's an article I found helpful for sorting out how alignment works:

[Alignment Guides in SwiftUI](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/)

Comment: Sorry for late, just got time to see my question. For sure, it is quite clear from your picture illustrated. To add a border to understand the alignment of VStack, text frame, text content. I feel weird too that we need to set one more .leading on the text content in the frame. Maybe apple will improve it since the SwiftUI layout design is pretty new.

Comment: Something to keep in mind (and the linked article goes into this) - is that even if you only use .frame(maxWidth: .infinity), the frame's alignment defaults to .center, so it's as if you used this: .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)

Answer (score 5):

You should add `.leading` alignment to its frame, like

```
 VStack(alignment: .leading) {
           Text("Haibo: asdasd").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
           Text("Jobs: WDC WDC WDC WDCWWWWW")
       }
```