# SwiftUI - Align Text in a VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

How to align a `Text` with left alignment in a `VStack` that is occupying more space like this
[image]

This is the code am using

```
VStack(alignment:.leading) {
    Text("Test")
       .font(.system(size: 10))
       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
 .background(Color.green)
```

Comment: How about some `padding`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add alignment to Text frame, like

```
VStack(alignment:.leading) {
    Text("Test")
       .font(.system(size: 10))
       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // << here !!
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
 .background(Color.green)
```

Comment: Thank you. Got the same from this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800624/how-to-keep-text-as-leading-alignment-after-set-text-framemaxwidth-infinity

Answer (score 2):

Try using this modifier on your Text view: `.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)`

Comment: Helpful if you have longer text which has an automatic linebreak into multiple lines.